# Call `heroku pg:restore` programmatically

Tags: heroku

I'm creating an app that mirrors my production app. As part of that, I want to copy over the production db every 24 hours. To do that, I imagine I'd use something like:

```
`heroku maintenance:on`
`heroku pg:restore DATABASE_COLOUR '#{prod_db_url}'`
`heroku maintenance:off`
```

But I imagine I need it to be run automatically as a rake task, but the heroku CLI tool isn't available on the heroku dyno.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Would you be better off setting up a *follower* database?

See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-follower-databases

Although not applicable to Hobby plans, this allows you to slave a database as a read-only copy of some other *master* database. This is managed automatically as part of the postgres functionality of Heroku and you won't have to set up any additional tasks.

Another approach along the lines you were thinking, using the Scheduler add-on (https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) is described here: https://blog.codeship.com/heroku-copy-database-between-apps/